# Function failing after unobtrusively setting attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I should note that all of my JavaScript is in the separate base.js file. In the following code I am

1) selecting a div

2) giving it an id and onlcick attribute

3) which calls a function i declare immediately after.

The function fails for some reason. I've tried putting the function first but still no success. The goal is that the divs background and innerHTML will change when the button is pressed. Any ideas why this doesn't work?

```js
var expand = document.querySelector("body div:first-child");
expand.setAttribute("id", "expand");
expand.addEventListener('click', expand);

function expand() {
  "use strict";
  expand.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  document.getElementById("expand").innerHTML = "hi";
}
```

```css
body{ text-align:center }

body div:first-child{
  float:left;width:28px;padding:5px;background:#fff;color:#666;cursor:pointer;
  font-size:150%
} 

body div:first-child:hover{
  background:#222; color:#eee
}

body div:first-child:active{background:#444; color:#fff}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div>+</div>
    <script src="js/base.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just `expand.addEventListener('click', expand);`?

Comment: Most likely the function isn't available in the global scope. You could do `window.expand = function() {...`, but you should be using `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for pointing this method out. I've replaced the `expand.setAttribute("onclick", "expand()");` line with yours but still the function fails to work as intended.

Comment: Why are you giving the element an id? You don't need an id given that you already have a reference to the element in the `expand` variable. And you don't need an id or the `expand` variable inside the event handler, because (assuming you attach it with `addEventListener`) you can just use `this`.

Comment: @nnnnnn I kept that part in the question because its there in my original code for later use. This element will need an id to make things easier for future code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions and variable declarations are both hoisted to the top of their containing scope, with functions hoisted first.

Because of this, your code is equivalent to:

```
function expand() {  //hoisted
  "use strict";
  expand.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  document.getElementById("expand").innerHTML = "hi";
}

var expand; //hoisted

expand = document.querySelector("body div:first-child");
expand.setAttribute("id", "expand");
expand.addEventListener('click', expand);
```

Essentially, the variable `expand` is *overriding* your function `expand`.

To fix it, just give your function a different name:

```js
var expand = document.querySelector("body div:first-child");
expand.setAttribute("id", "expand");
expand.addEventListener('click', fexpand);

function fexpand() {
  "use strict";
  expand.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  document.getElementById("expand").innerHTML = "hi";
}
```

```css
body{ text-align:center }

body div:first-child{
  float:left;width:28px;padding:5px;background:#fff;color:#666;cursor:pointer;
  font-size:150%
} 

body div:first-child:hover{
  background:#222; color:#eee
}

body div:first-child:active{background:#444; color:#fff}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div>+</div>
    <script src="js/base.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```